# Is an irreducible element still irreducible under localization?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a domain. We say an element $x\in R$ is "irreducible" if $x=yz$ implies that $y$ or $z$ is a unit or both are units. I want to know if an irreducible element is still an irreducible element when taking localization. If not, what is the "most simplest counterexample"? :)

> Let $R$ be a commutative domain with 1. Let $x$ be an irreducible element of $R$. Could we find some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, or a multiplicative set $S$, such that $x$ is not irreducible in $R_S$?

I allow $x$ to be a unit because it may become a unit in $R_x$.

**Note: the definition of irreducible here is not standard.**

Thanks.

---

As ones comment this it is an easy exercise, and should do it by myself. So I spend some times to think about it.

The $A=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ works. The element $2$ is irreducible in $A$, but it is reducible in $A_3$. Since $2\times 3=(1-\sqrt{-5})(1+\sqrt{-5})$. And $(1-\sqrt{-5})$
is not a unit in $A_3$, suppose it is a unit, then $(1-\sqrt{-5})*a=3^n$ for some $a\in A$ and $n$. Then taking norm will give a contradiction. Similar argument for $(1+\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: I think your definition for irreducible  is wrong, the equality $x=yz$ implies $y$ or $z$ have an inverse, not neccasarily that they are units.

Comment: @Belgi In a commutative ring, what is your distinction between having an inverse and being a unit? (In other words, I think wxu's definition is fine.)

Comment: Not answering wxu's question because it is a pretty basic homework question. Hint: You should try out a few of the basic examples of rings where irreducibles behave in an interesting way.

Comment: Isn't wxu's definition incorrect because it allows $x$ to be a unit? ([wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element))

Comment: @wxu: One does not usually consider units to be irredudible. You are really asking whether an irreducible will either stay irreducible or become a unit when passing to a localization.

Comment: Well , consider for example $\mathbb{R}[x]$, all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{R}$ have an inverse

Comment: @Belgi, UFD is still UFD under localization.

Comment: Indeed, $2x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ , but in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ it decompose to $2*x$, note that $2$ does not have an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I just said the definition for irreducible is wrong, I didn't talk about this case...

Comment: Please also note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD hence this is still worng for UFD's...