# $q$ irreducible $\Longrightarrow$ $q/1$ irreducible or unit in localization $S^{-1}R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I am trying to prove the following result:

*Let $R$ be a UFD and let $S \subset R$ be a multiplicative set.  Then if $q \in R$ is irreducible, either $q/1$ is a unit or is irreducible in $S^{-1}R$.*

I thought I had figured out a proof, but then I realized that I was implicitly assuming that all fractions $a/b \in S^{-1}R$ could be taken in ``reduced form'', i.e., $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.  Although this is certainly true for, say, the field of fractions over $R$, I do not see why it would generally true for an arbitrary localization.  It requires the property that if $a \in R$ and $b \in S$, then $b / \gcd(a, b) \in S$, and I am not convinced that this needs to be true.

**My question:** Does anybody know a proof of this result that does *not* assume reduced forms exist in $S^{-1}R$ (this would be the most desirable answer).  Alternatively, is there some proof that reduced forms always exist (I find this doubtful)?  Or, another possible alternative, does the result *fail* to hold for some $R$ and $S$ such that reduced forms do not exist?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129685/is-an-irreducible-element-still-irreducible-under-localization) for a counterexample.

Comment: If you are talking about the example with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, this ring is not a UFD.  I am considering localizations of UFDs.  It is, apparently, a standard fact that localizations of UFDs are UFDs, and, apparently, a standard claim in proving this fact that an irreducible in $R$ becomes either an irreducible or a unit when passed to the localization.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you were considering UFDs.

Comment: Isn't an irredicible a prime element in UFDs? When you localize, prime ideals either become the unit ideal or stay as a prime ideal in the localization.

Comment: @Youngsu:  Your statement is equivalent to 
$$q \in R \text{ irreducible } \Longrightarrow q \text{ unit or } q \text{ prime in } S^{-1}R,$$
which is just a slightly weaker version of my question, and an equivalent version given the fact that any localization of a UFD is a UFD (which I am not assuming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is irreducible in $R$. Then if $x$ divides some element of $S$, say $xy = s$ for $s\in S$, then $x$ clearly becomes a unit in $S^{-1}R$ since
$$\frac{x}{1}\cdot\frac{y}{s} = \frac{xy}{s} = 1.$$
in $S^{-1}R$.
Alternatively, if $x$ does not divide an element of $S$, then suppose that $x$ factors in $S^{-1}R$, say $x = \frac{y}{s'}\cdot\frac{z}{s''}$. Then $xs's'' = yz$. By unique factorization, $x$ must divide either $y$ or $z$. It cannot divide both since there is only one factor of $x$ on the LHS. Suppose it divides $y$. Then all irreducibles in the factorization of $z$ are divisors of $s'$ or $s''$ and thus divide some element of $S$. So  $\frac{z}{s''}$ must be a unit (by the first case) and thus $x$ is irreducible.

Comment: Very clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$ is called saturated if whenever $st\in S$ then $s,t\in S$. If $S$ is any multiplicative subset of $R$ then the set $\bar{S}$ of all those elements dividing some element of $S$ is saturated. It is easy to see that $S^{-1}R=\bar{S}^{-1}R$. Now it is clear that all fractions in $\bar{S}^{-1}R$ can be taken in reduced form.

Comment: Certainly, if $S$ is properly contained in $\bar{S}$, then $S^{-1}R \neq \bar{S}^{-1}R$.  You are saying that these are isomorphic as rings?

Comment: If you see every thing as subrings of the quotient ring of $R$ then $S^{-1}R=\bar{S}^{-1}R$. In fact, the image of $\bar{S}$ in $S^{-1}R$ is contained in the group of units and therefore the universal property provides an inclusion $\bar{S}^{-1}R\rightarrow S^{-1}R$